# Page loading progressively

Tags: php, for-loop, timeout

I'm building a basic scraping tool, which I'm running locally on my laptop, to backup data from a cms.

The basic procedural script that I wrote loads urls from a database and for each url, it scraps the page, saves the content to the database and then echoes that the page was successfully saved.

The problem is that when it manages to go through all the urls at once (a few hundreds of those at times), the output of the script loads progressively in my browser.

In Firefox I can see part of the echo statements for a few pages (indicating that the pages were saved), the rest comes in batches and at the bottom Firefox indicates me "Transferring data from localhost..."

I'm confused because I thought that when php script runs, it only outputs and sends a response as a single block, when it's done, and not like this, progressively.

Maybe I'm forgetting about something in my code? What do you think about it?

Here is the basic structure of my script:

```
<?php

try {
  // Login into the CMS
  // Connect to the DB to get the urls

  for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++) {
    // Get data from page
    $data = $scraper->getData($urls[$i]);

    // Store data from page
    if ( $db->save($data) ) {
      echo 'Data successfully saved for "' . $url[$i] . '"<br>';
    } else {
      echo 'Problem when saving data for "' . $url[$i] . '"<br>';    
    }
  }
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
}

?>
```

**I thought of using output buffering but the thing is that if the script fails or times out, then I thought I'm not going to get any output at all.**

Comment: You could do something client-side to make the page appear all at once instead of buffering the output. For example, put all the output in a `<div style="display: none">`, and then change the style of the `div` at the end of processing, using CSS or JavaScript. Or you could echo a JavaScript function that will display the output, and don't call the function until the end of processing.

Comment: @Lithis that still would not help him, since the end of the process would never finish due to the timeout, and the JS would not get printed. EDIT: Actually, theoretically if he put the JS in a document.ready it would wait until the script stops loading to run the JS and then show it all, so your solution may work

Comment: Yeah, my comment wasn't a fully-thought-out answer, and I should have said "at the end of page loading" instead of "at the end of processing", but I hoped it might give someone an idea for a more complete answer. Change the visibility when the page finishes loading, and hope that a timeout triggers the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some type of output buffer is what you would want to use.  You could also just append these to a string and echo the string when you're done:

```
<?php

try {
  // Login into the CMS
  // Connect to the DB to get the urls
  $html = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls); $i++) {
    // Get data from page
    $data = $scraper->getData($urls[$i]);

    // Store data from page
    if ( $db->save($data) ) {
      $html .= 'Data successfully saved for "' . $url[$i] . '"<br>';
    } else {
      $html .= 'Problem when saving data for "' . $url[$i] . '"<br>';    
    }
  }
  echo $html;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Just echoing in PHP starts sending the document immediately, even if the script does not finish loading. This is why you are seeing it happen line-by-line.

You could also look at ob_start() http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php . That is a standard way of echoing as you were, but holding the output until you are ready to show it all.

As @Lithis mentioned in the comment, if you want to wait to display the information only after the script has fully stopped running, you could wrap it in a

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

Then use Javascript on document.ready to change the display type to "block" to avoid it appearing line-by-line.

Comment: the problem is that most of the times, there are too many elements (urls) in the array and it does not loop through all the elements but times out. Would using output buffering prevent me from seeing any output in this case?

Comment: Yes, output buffering would prevent you from seeing the output if it times out.  The current way you are handling it is the only way you would get output in the case of timeout.  If timeout is an issue, you should use an ini_set or http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php to increase the allowed time